# Tomcat connection pool max connection

Tags: tcp, connection, tomcat7, threadpool

I got a Tomcat server with `maxActive="100"`. When There are more than 100 connections the 101, 102 ... are waiting for a connection.

Is there a way to tell Tomcat that if there are more connection than the `maxActive="100"` throw the connection with status 500 for example?

My goal is to not have a queue for connections. If there is no available connection return.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set `maxWait=0`, it will throw and exception immediately. If zero does not work, try 1. Zero is sometimes an special value.